# How to display data from the controller to partial view in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

now with the help of the community I have been able to do this, i'm trying to show the data from the controller to my partial view but i'm stuck,

In the main page i have this code:

```
@model Entidades.ViewModel.eTiendaOnlineViewModel
<div class="container my-4">
<h3 class="text-center">Los más vendidos</h3><hr />
@{

    Html.RenderPartial("vpprueba", Model.productosmasvendidos);
}
```

In my controller i have this:

```
using Entidades.ViewModel;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace TiendaOnline.Controllers
{
public class tiendaController : Controller
    {
        // GET: tienda
    public ActionResult index()
    {
        //Creo la entidad general
        eTiendaOnlineViewModel onlinestore = new eTiendaOnlineViewModel();
eClaseProductoViewModel clase1 = new eClaseProductoViewModel()
        {
            cod_clase_producto = "0001",
            descripcion = "CLASE NO. 1",
            imagen = "~/Content/images/alacena.jpg"
        };

        onlinestore.clasesproducto.Add(clase1);

        eClaseProductoViewModel clase2 = new eClaseProductoViewModel()
        {
            cod_clase_producto = "0002",
            descripcion = "CLASE NO. 2",
            imagen = "~/Content/images/Farmacia.jpg"
        };

        onlinestore.clasesproducto.Add(clase2);

        eClaseProductoViewModel clase3 = new eClaseProductoViewModel()
        {
            cod_clase_producto = "0003",
            descripcion = "CLASE NO. 3",
            imagen = "~/Content/images/pescado.jpg"
        };
    return View(onlinestore);
    }
```

And in my partial view i have this:

```
@model List<Entidades.ViewModel.eProductosViewModel>
@{
var id = "my-own-id";
var random = new Random();
var length = random.Next(10, 21);
var items = new List<Entidades.ViewModel.eProductosViewModel>();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    items.Add(new Entidades.ViewModel.eProductosViewModel
    {
//in this part is where I need to match the items variable for the data that comes to me from the controller to display it, I have tried to do it but I cannot do it

        //imagen1 = $"https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20({i + 21}).jpg",
        //descripcion_corta = $"Card Title {i + 1}"
    });
}

var itmIndex = 0;
var pages = items.Count / 3;

if (items.Count % 3 > 0)
{
    pages++;
}

<div id="@id" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Controls-->
    <div class="controls-top text-right my-2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle" href="#@id" data-slide="prev"><</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle" href="#@id" data-slide="next">></a>
    </div>
    <!--/.Controls-->
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                <li data-target="#@id" data-slide-to="@i" class="active"></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li data-target="#@id" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
            }
        }
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @for (int slide = 0; slide < pages; slide++)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item @(slide == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty)">
                <div class="row">
                    @for (int item = 0; item < 3; item++)
                    {
                        var m = items[itmIndex++ % pages];
                        var colCls = string.Empty;

                        if (item > 0)
                        {
                            colCls = "clearfix d-none d-md-block";
                        }
                        <div class="col-md-4 @colCls">
                            <div class="card mb-2">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="@m.imagen1" alt="Card image cap @(itmIndex + 1)">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">@m.descripcion_corta</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        Description text example
                                    </p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
</div>
}
```

Im using viewmodels for this, if anybody know how i can show the data from the controller to the view Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: You might want to check out this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-of-render-partial-view-in-mvc/
I think that you may be approaching the whole PartialView issue somewhat incorrectly.

Comment: How can I match the items variable to the values ​​returned by the controller so that I can iterate over each record and display it in the view?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly: your Index controller method should take a model (object) with the necessary information. Then, your partial view, when rendering, should consume items from your original model (object). That is, you should be referencing the child collection contained inside the the parent Model in your partial view.

Comment: In fact, that's how it is, as you can see in my controller I am simulating that I receive information from a database, that is, only working with the attributes of the model filling them with silly information to be able to show them on the screen and see how they will look. After that I return the general entity declared at the top of the action result called onlinestore along with the view. The partial view should be able to show the data that I am sending from the controller,but I don't know how to match the items variable that is in the partial view,show one by one in a bootstrap card